# Winforms -- multi select dropdown list

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I'm shopping around for a dropdown list control that allows me to select multiple items.  Something akin to the CheckedListbox, but in dropdown list form (I don't want it to take up a big chunk of the screen).  At this point I'm pretty convinced there is no such control built-in .NET.

Note this is Winforms, not ASP.NET. Any suggestions?

Comment: Use the control mentioned by Jim Lamb (http://www.codeproject.com/KB/combobox/extending_combobox.aspx ), but fix it by applying this fix from
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/simplepopup.aspx
in the forums, titled "Fix for focus problem with PopupComboBox.": In `Popupcombobox.cs` replace `ShowDropDown()` with BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(ShowDropDown)); in the method `protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)`. This made the focusing work for me, so far it feels nice now.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Check out this project on CodeProject:

- [CheckBox ComboBox Extending the ComboBox Class and Its Items](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/combobox/extending_combobox.aspx)

Comment: Seriously? Jeez.  This is exactly what I needed -- I wish I had posted this 24 hours ago!  Kudos.

Comment: In the end I gave up on this checkbox -- it's not as well polished as I first thought (in terms of recognizing mouse clicks, auto-complete, etc.).  I settled for using a pop up dialog box.  Still, definately worth knowing this exists.

Answer (score 11):

There is yet another fix:

The above solution is correct to fix the first issue, where it required two clicks to enter the list of checkboxes, however, this introduces a new issue when you click the control to exit it, it retains focus and you must double click to go to another control.  I was able to fix this with the following code:

In CheckBoxComboBox.cs add the following override:

```
    protected override void OnClick(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnClick(e);
        this.Parent.Focus();
    }
```

With the answer from Rob P. and this answer, it will not hold focus on either click event.

Comment: Yet another fix. As solved by Bat. Though that's a hack but needed one. Because your solution does good except while opening dropdown

Answer (score 3):

You should Show again the dropdown Form, because the code below closes it.

The code that Works is:

```
protected override void OnClick(EventArgs e)
{
        base.OnClick(e);
        this.Parent.Focus();
        this.dropDown.Show(this);
}
```

Comment: While this works, the `this.dropDown.Show(this)` causes some unintended side effects where the scrollbar requires an extra click or closes

Answer (score 3):

Here is another solution which works better for me from a UI perspective, I find the UI more refined and code easier to use/understand:

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31105/A-ComboBox-with-a-CheckedListBox-as-a-Dropdown

Note there are a couple of fixes required to avoid the double click issue which can be found in the comments. Quoting from Herrpel (9-May-17)

Add this to the outer class CheckedComboBox

```
protected override void OnMouseDown(MouseEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnMouseDown(e);
    DroppedDown = false;
}
```

and for the Windows 10 losing focus on closing the box issue, change the code in `CloseDropdown`:
from

```
ccbParent.Focus();
this.Hide();
```

to

```
ccbParent.BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(() => this.Hide()));
```

Comment: Also, another fix would be needed: to be able to use the **DropDownList** style. For this there is a comment by 'William Vincent' - however does not work for me. @rboy, maybe you know how to apply that comment? Thanks

Comment: I found the solution: you have to change _OwnerDrawVariable_ to _Normal_ in the properties window. Otherwise it won't work.