# How to Selecting a More than one items in Combobox using C# WinForms

Tags: c#, sql-server, windows, winforms

Here I have added a code for adding a items into Combobox using database but i don't know how to use a multiple select items in Combobox....?

```
        admin = "Admin";
        string query = "Select FirstName from Register where UserType =  '" + admin + "'  ";
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(query, con);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds);
        comboBox1.Text = "--- Select an Admin Here ---";
        foreach (DataRow dr1 in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
        {
            comboBox1.Items.Add(dr1["FirstName"].ToString());
        }
```

Comment: are you trying to select the items or still just add them?

Comment: i did add the items into combobox but i dont know ,how to select a multiple items in combobox...?

Comment: ComboBox is not multi select.

Comment: @RezaAghaei  Have any solution for this...?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3118174/winforms-multi-select-dropdown-list/11314568

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Winforms -- multi select dropdown list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3118174/winforms-multi-select-dropdown-list)

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
ListBox listBox1 = new ListBox();
// Set the SelectionMode to select multiple items.
listBox1.SelectionMode = SelectionMode.MultiExtended;

// Select three initial items from the list.
listBox1.SetSelected(0, True);
listBox1.SetSelected(2, True);
listBox1.SetSelected(4, True);
```

Comment: But thats a list box

Comment: Combobox does not contain or extension method in  "Selectionmode"